# There is a sometimes fully faithful functor from simplicial commutative algebras to differential graded algebras. What is this functor explicitly?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, homotopy-theory, simplicial-stuff, higher-category-theory, model-categories

In [Jacob Lurie's paper "Derived Algebraic Geometry,"](http://people.math.harvard.edu/%7Elurie/papers/DAG.pdf) in 2.6 **$E_{\infty}$-Ring Spectra and Simplicial Commutative Rings**, page 25, there is the following claim:

> In general, we have functors $\mathcal{SCR}_{R/}\xrightarrow{\phi}\mathcal{DGA}_{R}\xrightarrow{\psi}\mathcal{EI}_{R/}$. If $R$ is a $\mathbf{Q}$-algebra, then $\psi$ is an equivalence of $\infty$-categories, $\phi$ is fully faithful, and the essential image of $\phi$ consists of the connective objects of $\mathcal{DGA}_{R}\simeq\mathcal{EI}_{R/}$ (that is, those algebras $A$ having $\pi_{i}A=0$ for $i<0$).

What is the explicit functor $\phi:\mathcal{SCR}_{R/}\to\mathcal{DGA}_{R}$? I suppose that the natural thing would be to take a simplicial $R$-algebra $A$ and assign it to
\begin{align*}
\phi(A)=\bigoplus_{i=0}^{\infty}\pi_{i}A,
\end{align*}
and take a map $f:A\to B$ and assign it to
\begin{align*}
\phi(f)=\bigoplus_{i=0}^{\infty}(f_{i}:\pi_{i}A\to\pi_{i}B),
\end{align*}
but as far as I could find this isn't stated explicitly in DAG. Is this the case, and if so, do you have a source or proof? And how does one show that $\bigoplus\pi_{i}A$ is a differential graded algebra?

Comment: This is just a guess, but it might be simply given by the Dold-Kan correspondence (this version in [nLab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/monoidal+Dold-Kan+correspondence)).

Answer (score 1):

The functor SCR→CDGA is given by the normalized chains functor N: sAb→Ch
on underlying objects without multiplication,
and the multiplication is given by the composition NA⊗NA→N(A⊗A)→NA,
where the first map is the Eilenberg–Zilber map and the second map
is the normalized chains functor applied to the multiplication map A⊗A→A.
The Eilenberg–Zilber map is symmetric, so the above construction indeed lands in commutative differential graded algebras.

See Schwede and Shipley, [Equivalences of monoidal model categories](http://arxiv.org/abs/math.AT/0209342) for the case of associative algebras.
For the commutative case several references can be found at the [nLab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/monoidal+Dold-Kan+correspondence).